# Can PMD, FindBugs, and Checkstyle be used together for a Java development project? Does it lead to wide overlapping of functions?

Tags: checkstyle, findbugs, sonarqube, pmd

Can PMD, FindBugs, and Checkstyle be used together for a Java development project? Does it lead to wide overlapping of functions? Or else, can the same results be achieved using Sonar instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use PMD, FindBugs and Checkstyle together for a Java development project. There will be overlap, so you will have to select the rules that you activate accordingly. You could start with the default rulesets and then see which findings are being reported by more than one tool.

Using SonarQube (formerly Sonar) will also work. SonarQube uses all three tools (and more) under the hood. Using the SonarQube plugin for your IDE, you can also see the SonarQube findings in your code directly. However, you may still run into some overlap depending on your configuration. Chances are smaller though. SonarQube has recently begun providing their own detectors for much of the Checkstyle, PMD, and FindBugs functionality. Those SonarQube provided detectors have little to no overlap among themselves. Also, the "Sonar Way" default ruleset is configured so that there is no overlap.

However, if you want to utilize static code analysis professionally, you must be prepared to spend a significant amount of time configuring and fine-tuning the toolchain. After a while, the question of overlap becomes less present, and you will develop opinions on which detector implementation is best for your situation.